# Missing option value : installPath

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I try to install packages to MVS2017 I get this error. How can I fix it?

[[image]]

Comment: Explain what exactly you did ("When I try to install packages to MVS2017").

Comment: Have you tried to install from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

It did some research and found that there's some kind of a bug, many people have faced this problem. Try using this

> "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\installer\vs_installershell.exe" repair --installPath="c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\Community"

from Command Prompt and run as administrator

Comment: doesn't work, just starts the installer and says the path is missing even if that path exists....